# Vaadin LitRenderer bean exposure to the client

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Currently I'm using ComponentRenderers in my Vaadin application, but I would like to change it to LitRenderer (for better performance).

I read the documentation and I'm not sure about the "Note". Does it mean that the whole Person bean is exposed to the client, or only the Address bean from the example? I'm asking because I would like to use it for User bean which contains passwords...

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/flow#using-lit-renderers

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the notes you have screenshoted. Only / all properties of the address is send to the client. If you would supply the user instance, the whole user instance' properties would be available in the client.